# Can't load 20.4 alongside Win 10 in an HP ProDesk w/ a Toshiba SSD

Tags: dual-boot

Using HP ProDesk and can't load 20.4 alongside Windows 10.  I get a message to disable bitlocker, and when I go to windows settings, bitlocker is not active.  How do I get past this?

Comment: Is fast startup enabled in Windows? If so, it is known to create problems like this with dual-boots, and I'd recommend disabling it. [This article](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup) explains how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I disabled fast startup, but that did not solve the problem.   I notice that while Control Panel (etc) says bitlocker is not active, Disk Management for the Toshiba SSD says it is!  I can keep using 20.04 from the flash drive, however I would prefer to have it along side Win10.  Oh well ...